# Ping between bridged networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

My Network Diagram:
[image]

`Router1 (Router to Internet)` is a router that goes to the Internet. Everything is fine with it.

`Switch0 (Just a switch)` is a normal switch.

`Access Point0 (Access Point)` is a wireless antenna. It's in access point mode. `It's IP is 10.7.7.5 and gateway is 10.5.5.1`. It's connected with `Wireless Router3(Station-Router)`.

`Wireless Router3(Station-Router)` is a wireless antenna that is in Station-router mode. It's connected with Access Point0. It has `WAN IP: 11.7.7.128`, and `LAN IP: 192.168.1.1`. It has a DHCP server running on it as well. Whenever I plug my PC to this device I can go to the Internet and ping everything on network.

`Router3` - the router that is connected to `Wireless Router3(Station-Router)`. When I connect to this device with my PC I can't ping anywhere. I know that I have to make routing from that router, but don't know from where to where.

Comment: Are you sure its a routing issue? I've worked with a lot of home-grade routers (both wired and wireless, and in bridged scenarios) where there is absolutely no way to disable NAT and Firewalling. That will mean that you will not be able to ping across that router (NAT doesn't support port forwarding for ICMP), or use other protocols unless you create port forwarding rules for them.  Is there no way to configure Router3 as an AP rather than a router?

Comment: You really need to include the subnet masks in your graphic. Without knowing the subnets it's not possible to properly understand your network's design.

Answer (score 0):

I will consider some info that is not very clear in your diagram:

- 196.18.120.252/30 is the network configured that is linking your `Station-Router` and `Router3`

If this is true, please check:

1. if the default route in `Router3` points to the `Station-Router`
2. if the `Station-Router` knows that all the networks you're using on `Router3` are reachable via `Router3`.

As `Station-Router` seems to have only a default route configured, it will try to reach your device connected in `Router3` via it's default route, which is the Internet, unless you specifically add a route on it to the network your device is plugged via `Router3`.